# Tor starting up but at times Firefox/Iceweasel doesn't show up

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I am on Debian and at times everything happens except that Iceweasel/Firefox doesn't run.

```
$ tor

Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US

(process:6455): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:6455): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:6455): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:6455): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:6455): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Sep 07 02:21:53.744 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.23 (git-a9ea51dc0bd48126) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1i.
Sep 07 02:21:53.744 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 07 02:21:53.744 [notice] Read configuration file "/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults".
Sep 07 02:21:53.744 [notice] Read configuration file "/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/torrc".
Sep 07 02:21:53.749 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
Sep 07 02:21:53.750 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151
Sep 07 02:21:53.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/fteproxy.bin --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.

Sep 07 02:21:53.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/obfsproxy.bin managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 07 02:21:53.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 07 02:21:53.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/geoip.
Sep 07 02:21:53.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/geoip6.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] We now have enough directory information to build circuits.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] New control connection opened.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/fteproxy.bin --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/obfsproxy.bin managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.

Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] New control connection opened.
Sep 07 02:21:54.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop.
Sep 07 02:21:55.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit.
Sep 07 02:21:56.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Sep 07 02:21:56.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.
Sep 07 02:21:57.000 [notice] New control connection opened.
```

After this nothing and you get a short window saying Firefox is running but not showing or words to that effect. If I run ps ux I get the following two entries :-

```
$ps ux 

shirish   6443  0.0  0.0   4308   692 pts/0    S+   02:21   0:00 /bin/sh /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser

shirish   6473  0.2  1.1  47216 24552 pts/0    S+   02:21   0:01 /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Tor/tor --deb
```

Looking forward for solutions.